# How to set Unchanged First Letter in EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to force displaying an alphabet in EditText which can't delete but clicking Backspace.
ex. [#____________]
in above example, # is default for that edittext field. When using Edittext.gettext() it should returns '#32343'

Comment: I'll try posting a snippet soon, but in the meantime check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#beforeTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, int).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways come to mind immediately, but I'm admittedly confused by your question. It seems like you want to (instead of displaying an empty EditText) display an EditText with a letter at the beginning. If that's the case, try this:

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

// default characters to display
// replace "#" with whatever you like
final String defaultTextDisplayed = "#";

// text is either set here or via xml, preferably via strings.xml
et.setText(defaultTextDisplayed);

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // ignored
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // ignored
    }

    // This is the callback we're interested in. Any time
    // your user edits what is in the EditText, this method
    // is called. We'll use it listen for when a user tries
    // to delete the default display text.
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // if the user attempts to delete and of the default
        // string displayed, just put it back
        if (s.length() < defaultTextDisplayed.length()) { 
            et.setText(defaultTextDisplayed);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this won't show the # untill the user starts typing something !

Comment: Thanks @LeonardoFerrari for pointing that out. I (perhaps errantly assumed) that the text would be set initially via XML. Indeed, the defaultTextDisplayed would have to be set on the EditText somewhere else in this code. Do you think I should edit my code to clarify?

Comment: You are welcome. Perhaps you should set before `et.addTextChangedListener` the '#' in the EditText, what do you think ?

Comment: Looks great @halfjew22 ! Way to go ;)

Comment: No.. I wanted that, user doesn't need to add # in edittext filed. The content in editext must be in the format - #23. in this case, user need to type only 23. but # must be prefix to 23. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, this code will do that. The user doesn't need to enter #.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `TextChangedListener` where you make sure those parts of your text wont get deleted/overwritten.

Try this code

```
final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

edt.setText("#");
Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());


edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!s.toString().contains("#")){
                edt.setText("#");
                Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());

            }

        }
    });
```